# How can I have GitHub return the actual file (not displayed in the Git viewer)?

Tags: github

We have all of our API documentation up on Git. But when I go to [the index.html file](https://github.com/windward-studios/Windward-REST-version-2-Clients/blob/master/.Net%20Standard%202.0/dotnetdoc/index.html), I get it in a viewer. Is there a way to have it return the raw html file, for that one and all the ones it links to?

Comment: Use the raw.githubusercontent subdomain https://raw.githubusercontent.com/windward-studios/Windward-REST-version-2-Clients/master/.Net%20Standard%202.0/dotnetdoc/index.html

Comment: Or do you mean that you want it interpreted as HTML?

Comment: @zero298 Yes, interpreted as HTML so it comes up as the javadoc

Answer (score 0):

You should publish your repository as [GitHub page](https://pages.github.com/), specifically a [project site](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#types-of-github-pages-sites) available at `http(s)://<user>.github.io/<repository>`

[Configure the publication source](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#choosing-a-publishing-source) to be your `master` branch, and you would then be able to go to https://windward-studios/Windward-REST-version-2-Clients/.Net%20Standard%202.0/dotnetdoc

Comment: I want to make it part of the project. The project has the sample code, binaries (for people who can't/don't use NuGet) and then the dotnetdoc html. All in the same place. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @DavidThielen Possibly move your document in a `docs/` folder, which can be used as a source for your GitHub Pages project. The root folder would then be for your sample code.

Comment: It's in a dotnetdocs folder (and sub-folders). Is the docs folder name special? Or is there a way to say a folder and sub-folders should just return the file itself? TIA

Comment: @DavidThielen Yes, `docs/` is one of the publication sources: see https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#choosing-a-publishing-source